# How to set X-Robots-Tag in IIS environment based on a certain url?

Tags: iis, canonical-link, x-robots-tag

I have a HTML page like `https://www.example.com/page1.html`. On this page, anywhere in the source code exists a link to a PDF file, like `<a href="https://www.example.com/a-cryptic-id/file1.pdf">my file</a>`. There could be multiple links to multiple PDF files on the same HTML page.

My goal is, using `X-Robots-Tag`, to set a `canonical` link for the PDF file to the page, where the file is linked on.

Expected result: `https://www.example.com/a-cryptic-id/file1.pdf` has a header entry `<link rel="canonical" href="https://www.example.com/page1.html">`

There are multiple cases, so I'm looking for a solution based on mechanics like `all PDF files on this page get the page url into canonical`.

I'm in IIS environment.

Comment: Things range from URL rewrite rules to custom IIS extensions.

Comment: @LexLi could you please provide some details to your answer?